# SQL insert into a table depending on values in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert-into

I am creating a library system that only has 1 copy of each book. The user would enter the book and the dates they want it for. After the system would check that the book is not reserved for the dates the user wants it.

I'm trying to insert data into a table if the variables are not already in the table. e.g. if the id is equal to 3 and the date is in between two dates already in the table, then the information won't be entered. The table is for a simple book reservation system. The code below is what I have, but doesn't seem to work so needs changing. The error that I get is below the code. Thank you.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` 
INSERT INTO table_name (name, id, start_date, end_date, days)
VALUES ('test', '4', '0000-00-00', '1000-00-00', 3)
WHERE id != 3
AND start_date NOT BETWEEN 2016-03-31 AND 2016-03-05
```

This is the error that I get when I run the code:

```
 Static analysis:

9 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT" at position 203)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "BETWEEN" at position 207)
Unexpected token. (near "2016" at position 215)
Unexpected token. (near "-03" at position 219)
Unexpected token. (near "-31" at position 222)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "AND" at position 226)
Unexpected token. (near "2016" at position 230)
Unexpected token. (near "-03" at position 234)
Unexpected token. (near "-05" at position 237)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT * FROM `table_name` INSERT LIMIT 0, 25 INTO table_name (name, id, start_date, end_date, days) VALUES ('test', '4', '0000-00-00', '1000-00-00', 3) WHERE id != 3 AND start_date NOT BETWEEN 2016-03-31 AND 2016-03-05

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT LIMIT 0, 25 INTO table_name (name, id, start_date, end_date, days)' at line 3#
```

Comment: First of all your [insert into - select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)  syntax is not correct.

Comment: @Smudger you cannot have a where clause in your insert statement because you are inserting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to just do the two things separately, in different parts of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You problably want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, id, start_date, end_date, days)
SELECT name, id, start_date, end_date, days
FROM (SELECT 'test' AS name, 
             4 AS id, 
             '0000-00-00' AS start_date, 
             '1000-00-00' AS  end_date, 
             3 AS days) AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM table_name
                  WHERE id = 3 AND start_date BETWEEN '2016-03-31' AND '2016-03-05')
```

This query will insert the specified *hardcoded* values in `table_name` **if** a row with `id=3` **and** `start_date` between dates `('2016-03-31', '2016-03-05')` **does not exist** in the same table.

You can modify the predicates of the `WHERE` clause as you wish to suit your actual needs.

Comment: Only problem with that is, if it has the same id and is in between the two dates it will still enter the data into the table, the opposite of what I want to happen.

Comment: @Smudger I'm afraid I don't understand your actual requirement. You want to insert and `id` and dates that *already* exists in the table?

Comment: What I want to do is, if a book is already reserved then the book can't be borrowed at the same time. So if the dates are in between a date that has already been entered into the table, and the book id is the same. Then the book can't be reserved. Basically it is a library with only 1 copy of each book.

Comment: @Smudger In that case `NOT EXISTS` seems to be what you want: it can prevent a duplicate record from being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are inserting data from same table as you are selecting. Is it what you want?
2. Do you only want to insert `VALUES ('test', '4', '0000-00-00', '1000-00-00', 3)` in the table? In that case why the `where` clause.
3. If you want to select data from your table based on condition you want, then why are you clubbing `VALUES ('test', '4', '0000-00-00', '1000-00-00', 3)` with it? You need separate insert statement for it.
4. The value used for `between` clause should have smaller value on left and bigger on right. Also you should ideally typecast it. `start_date NOT BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2016-03-05','%Y-%m-%d')  and STR_TO_DATE('2016-03-31','%Y-%m-%d')`
5. Last but not the least, `insert` clause comes before `select`.

Please answer the questions and/or change your query based on these inputs.

Edit: Based on OP comments, generated 2 insert statements. Instead of using `statement2`, you can use `union` and select values from `dual` but I am not sure on date typecast in that case in `mysql`.

`Statement1:`

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, id, start_date, end_date, days)
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` WHERE id != 3
AND start_date NOT BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2016-03-05','%Y-%m-%d')  and STR_TO_DATE('2016-03-31','%Y-%m-%d')
```

`Statement2`

```
insert into table_name (name, id, start_date, end_date, days)
values ('test', '4', '0000-00-00', '1000-00-00', 3)
```

Comment: 1) Yes I want to insert into the same table, 2) Yes that data would be entered, however is only an example, 3) I thought that was how it should be done

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` (INSERT LIMIT 0, 25 INTO table_name 
(name, id, start_date, end_date, days) 
VALUES ('test', '4', '0000-00-00', '1000-00-00', 3))
WHERE id != 3 AND start_date NOT BETWEEN '2016-03-31' AND '2016-03-05'
```